# the computer says c:\Documents does not exist

Tags: google-chrome

- In "users", your bookmarks, history remains public.
- In "profiles" it remains private

There is a [detailed tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/software/create-family-profiles-in-google-chrome/4394/). However in the lest step I get an error:

```
c:\Documents does not exist.
```

Comment: Welcome, but please see [How to ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer) and [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). Thanks.

Comment: @Arjan: You surely wanted to link [How to ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) ;)

Answer (score 2):

The folder is:

> C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data

This has spaces in the name. If you are passing this as an argument to a script you need to enclose it in quotes:

> "C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data"

Otherwise Windows will split the string at the spaces - which is why you get the error reported as

> "C:\Documents" does not exist.

Comment: thanks a lot sir so should i post "C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir="..\User Data\Your_Name"......but i am still getting an error that it does not exist..... perhaps there is a different flavour to it.....actually there is a  " even after --user-data-dir.should i try replacing spaces with %

Comment: @shrenuj 1. replace `<user>` with your user name. 2. close the quotes after `chrome.exe`.

Comment: MAGIC!solved the problem.how can i repay this help to you Sir ChrisF

Comment: By accepting the answer. Click on the check mark and you will on way have fun here.